# Selecting the first child image tag using angular directive and jqLite

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I have a directive that I loop through called `waPages`.

Inside this tag are a few child nodes; one of which, is an image tag.

**TEMPLATE:**

```
<li wa-pages page="page" ng-repeat="page in carousel.pages"></li>
```

**inner template:**

```
<div id="page-{{page.pageindex}}">
  <img  ng-src="{{page.imageurl}}" on-load />
</div>
```

### **Question:**

**How can I select this image tag and get the inner width/height**

**Pages Directive:**

```
angular.module('carouselApp')
.directive('waPages',  function (Pages, Carousel) {
    return {
        scope: {
            page: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'views/wa.pages.html',
        transclude: true,
        require: '^waCarousel',
        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
            //this wont work obviously
            var imageWidth = el[0].find('img:first-child').innerWidth;
        }
    }

});
```

Update hers my `console.log(el[0]);`

[image]

Comment: register onload on the image and set src, or create a temporary image element set same src and on load of it calculate innerwidth. Your selector is not correct as well.

Comment: use like this `var imageWidth = $(el).find('img:first').width();`

Comment: I'm not using jquery only jqlite

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/7JCwPC?p=preview

Comment: I can even set the timeout to 30seconds or select it directly via .children a few times still nothing innerWidth is comign up undefined

Comment: What if your image takes more than 30 sec :P I would go with onload event.. you can always trust.. :) What do you mean by innerWidth on the image? what's wrong with `.find('img')`? You have more img tags under the same li?

Comment: No I agree your method is better but even if I do make the timeout 30seconds it comes up as undefined!   I feel like the problem is something else with my code :(

Comment: Did you try that? see the console in my demo. Are your images fixed width and you want to get the orignial width of the image?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/63375/discussion-between-matthew-harwood-and-psl).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just extending my comment to answer, you could set up `onload` event on the img tag. So once image is loaded grab its dimensions. Also note the selector as well.

Remove ng-src from your template and set it on the element directly:-

```
.directive('waPages',  function ($window) {
    return {
        scope: {
            page: "="
        },
        templateUrl: 'wa.pages.html',
        transclude: true,

        link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
           var $img = el.find('img')[0]; //get the image
            $img.src = scope.page.imageurl; //set the url

            $img.onload = function() {
              console.log(this.width, this.height); //Get height and width
            }
        }
    }
});
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/7JCwPC?p=preview)**

If you have set a specific height and width for the image via css, loading images with different dimensions will not fetch you true dimensions. In such cases you can get its original width from [`naturalWidth/naturalHeight`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLImageElement) property of the image (not supported in older browsers).

```
 link: function (scope, el, attrs, ctrl) {
       var $img = el.find('img')[0];
        //Just set ng-src itself
        //$img.src = scope.page.imageurl;

        $img.onload = function() {
          console.log(this.naturalWidth, this.naturalHeight);
        }
    }
```

**[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N3sCOF?p=preview)**

You could also create a temporary image tag and load the image src and grab its height and width as well. **[Plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/VmfI4F?p=preview)**